# java Template for class fields

Tags: java

I have 3 classes with different fields:

```
Class Cow(){
private integer legs;
private integer eyes;}

Class Fish(){
private integer fins;
private integer eyes;}

Class Pinguin(){
private integer legs;
private integer fins;
private integer eyes;}
```

I want to make sure that the fields are valid / allowed fields. Is there any design pattern for this ?
If I use inheritance from Animal() then the Cow may have fins which I want to avoid. I just want that fins is called fins and not 'FiN' or 'fiins' in the subclass. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

This is basic object oriented design. Just follow the real world as close as possible. Create a base class Animal() with subclasses like Birds(), Mammals(), Insects() and so on. Go further down in that tree.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent class which will have all the common properties and then extend the parent class in the child class. In this case:

```
class Animal{
    protected int eyes;
}

class Cow extends Aminal{
    protected int legs;
}
```

The `Animal` class is the parent class whereas the `Cow` is a child class which extends `Animal`, and will also contain the data member `eyes`.

Also, check the syntax of the statements. Your classes won't compile.